# Is this a typo on Wikipedia about pushforward of vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry

In [this section on pushforward of vector fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29#Pushforward_of_vector_fields) the following is stated:

(second paragraph): A section of $\phi^\ast TN$ over $M$ is called a vector field along $\phi$.

> Shouldn't this be  "A section of $\phi^\ast TM$"?

I believe if $\phi$ is a map $M \to N$ then $\phi^\ast$ is a map $TM \to TN$. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia entry is correct. $\phi^* TN$ is the [pullback bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle); it wouldn't make sense to write $\phi^* TM$ since $\phi: M \to N$ has $M$ as its source. This is an example of a more general construction: [pullbacks in category theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28category_theory%29). If you want to know more, see the section on pullbacks in [Awodey's text](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199237182).